# Process large headers from 8Kb to 1 MB on haproxy using tune.bufsize and tune.maxrewrite

Tags: haproxy

Currently I am doing a POC on haproxy where we need to get the TR time which is the time taken to receive http header.
I have currently set

```
tune.bufsize 131702
tune.maxrewrite 32768
```

but I am not able to send header more than 8k

I get 400 Bad Request
Request Header Or Cookie Too Large
error

Comment: The error may not come from haproxy but from your backend server. Check your HAProxy logs for the termination state. If it is `----` then the error is created by your backend server (where you likely need to increase the header limit too). In any case, please edit your question and add a representative log line from HAProxy.

Comment: Request is not reaching backend server and no log line is printed on haproxy.
Earlier it was working for some value of bufsize and maxrewrite . But I don't remember those values now